# Meteor Iron Route is not reactive when in iframe?

Tags: meteor, leaflet, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I´m developing a map app in meteor with leaflet. To show data in a marker popup I created a route and call it from and iframe on the popup. When I display the route alone, it's reactive. When the same route is displayed in the popup, it's not. 
I have set up a route with Iron Route. When I navigate to the page everything is OK.
If I  put the route in an iframe in another meteor page it renders but is not reactive..

Code below:

Template

```
<template name="prueba">
    {{#each Clientes}}
       {{Nombre}} 

    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Route

```
Router.route('/prueba', function () {
  this.render('prueba');
});
```

Helper

```
Template.prueba.helpers ({

  Clientes: function() {

    return clientes.find({ lunes: Session.get("Lunes") });
    }

  });
```

Popup

```
map.on('locationfound', function(e){
      position= new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon:gpsIcon});
      position.addTo(map);
      map.setZoom(18);
      position.bindPopup('<iframe src="/prueba"  style="border:none"> </iframe>').openPopup();
    });
```

Comment: Just an idea: try putting the html into a session instead of a template and call it in `position.bindPopup(session.get('clientes')).openPopup();`

Comment: I created a repo with the solution: https://github.com/vchigne/dynaTemplates